If I was living purely on my state pension, I have to work
This is from native english speaker TV channel. Pensioners cut (see:0:29-0:44)
TV presenter Good morning to you both. So Rob you are just a couple of pounds over the threshold but it means you're going to lose out on hundreds in Winter fuel allowance.
Guest: that's quite correct. that's if I was living purely on my state pension I have to work right um to to bolster my income.
The guest is talking about an unreal situation "If I was living purely on my state pension", however he goes on to say "I have to work"., whereas he is supposed to say "I would have to work", isn't he?
Is there a reason he said it this way or is it simply a mistake of the speaker?

The speaker is saying (new statement) "I have to work [pause] to bolster my income.“ This makes complete sense.

Don't forget that in conversation, people do make slight errors of grammar and word selection. It's subconsciously ignored by native speakers because they know what the speaker means, but when written down / transcribed it becomes apparent.

"If I was living purely on my state pension" is the unreal situation, but he isn't. He goes on to say "I have to work", therefore he is working.

@Mari-LouA Do you think he meant "I would have to work to bolster my income" ? Or for the full sentence "If I only had my state pension, I would have to work to bolster my income"

This is not a suitable question for the site. Once again, we cannot grammar-check the extemporaneous speech of every non-professional broadcaster who gets a camera pointed at them. Transcripts of unscripted speech cannot be scrutinised like this.

@PeterJennings What he meant and what he actually said are two different things. I can only confirm that "I have to work (= must) to bolster my income" refers to the present.

Why don't you ask if it's ungrammatical to use "um" in a sentence?

Thank you @Astralbee for Transcripts of unscripted speech cannot be scrutinised.

Um, thank you @StuartF.

This should be kept open as it teaches a useful lesson about stress and intonation in English. You don't learn by writing only. You learn by listening.

I’m voting to close this question because the speaker was misheard.


TV Presenter: Rob, you are just a couple of pounds over the threshold but it means you're going to lose out on hundreds in winter fuel allowance.
Rob: That's quite correct, that's if I was living purely on my state pension. I have to work, erm, to bolster my income–I'm in private rent and that takes most of it.

I have to work [now] [in order] to bolster my income.
This statement is perfectly grammatical, the speaker has no choice but to continue working despite being 68 years old, and eligible for a state–not private–pension.

See my comment above.

@MichaelHarvey I don't know or fully understand how this pension "credit" works but the interviewer summarised this situation very well: The government is going to increase state pensions so more people will pass the threshold, and  as a result lose their winter allowance. If someone earns just two pounds a week over the threshold, their allowance is removed. I can't imagine what it must be like living in the north of England or Scotland and not have the heating on every day when October, November, December and January arrives.

When the government increases the State Pension they increase the threshold for Pension Credit payments at the same time.

Would it be picky to expect If I were?

@MichaelHarvey I don't know how the system works, I'm living in Italy and there is no such thing as subsidised heating for OAPs, and some parts of Italy can be freezing cold in the winter.  Luckily, wooden and pellet stoves are very common, and now with all these solar panels many people (unfortunately not the neediest who cannot afford these instalments) should  be saving costs.

@YosefBaskin it might be pedantic :) It's fine saying "if I was living on my state pension" because it's not an irrealis situation

+1.  The OP misheard/misparsed the utterance."I have to work" is a new sentence. Full stop after "pension". "I have to work"  could have been preceded with the word "But".

Right, it was incorrectly parsed. +1 This example is excellent for those interested in stress and intonation in English. His entire expression changes.
